# Div with absolute positioning not taking full height of TD (IE issue)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table where the first column spans multiple rows. I'm trying to add a side-border to it with some nice padding (not absolutely glued in the corners).
Hence I thought to just draw an absolutely positioned div in the td.
Unfortunately, in IE the absolutely positioned div is calculated based on the single row height, not the height of the actual td. 
Can anyone help figure this out? [JSfiddle available](https://jsfiddle.net/8g2dc2k3/) =)

Thanks!

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}
.side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 5px;
}
.one {
  background-color: orange;
}
.two {
  background-color: blue;
}
.three {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="one" rowspan="2">
      <div class="side"></div>
      1

    </td>
    <td class="two">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="three">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In case you didnt try it, try height 100% as well.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar I did try, JSFiddle is now attached. Open it in IE, obviously =)

Comment: Well there is a known issue, td element positioning relative will not work, it's undefined, but maybe you can try this:  https://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar Shoot, that only works if the wrapper has a fixed pixel height (set by jquery: el.height()). My table rows will change their height at runtime (expanding/collapsing groups). With 50-60 lines of javascript it would eventually work, but would still prefer a couple of clean CSS lines...

Comment: You might be better off giving the td a border-right.

Comment: Can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8g2dc2k3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position relative on td's is undefined as per the css spec. So there need not be consistent results for this. I can suggest an alternate solution, which is to apply the styles directly to the td itself:

```
.one {
  background-color: orange;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  outline: 5px solid orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8g2dc2k3/2/

Of course that might mean adjusting styling for other td's to manage the border spacing.

It is a bit unconventional and I am using outline property for td to be same as the background colour in order to make this work.

Comment: Thank you for persisting, Arathi! Using outline, border & padding I can indeed change my existing border & padding to get the effect I want, on all browsers, without Javascript!  =)